# Android - Detect when an application goes to foreground

Tags: android, service

My application need to do something when another application goes to foreground (Facebook for example). Other topics did not work for me. Here is my code.

Obs.: in the line :

```
(ActivityManager) BackGroundService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

I tried to use context instead of `BackGroundService.this`, but it doesn't work.

```
while(true){
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) BackGroundService.this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        Iterator<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()) {
                info = i.next();
                if (info.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    notificar("ola");
                }

                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
          }
   }
```

Comment: This seems not clear enough. Could you provide more context maybe? You should also use _code snippet_ only when you can actually run the code on SO, otherwise, there's _code sample_ which only highlights code.

Comment: I will edit and add all service that i'am working.